# Column Color in report designer using expression

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting, telerik-open-access

i am new to the telerik reporting. i am using the following expression in my report,

**= Fields.EmailPromotion +" " + "Y"**

i want to show emailpromotion in color RED and "Y" in color green.can some one please tell me how to do this using the expression . any help will be appreciated. 
i am using report designer R2 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve different styles within the same text box you will need to switch from **TextBox** to **HtmlTextBox**. Then you need to go to the "Expression..." editor for the HtmlTextBox and then switch from "Design View" to "Html view". Once you are in "Html View" enter the following expression:

```
    ="<span style='color: #ff0000'>" + Fields.EmailPromotion + "</span> "
               + "<span style='color: #00ff00'>Y</span>"
```

Hope this helps.